# jQuery getting class

Tags: jquery

```
            $(document).ready(function(){

      $('img').click(function(){
 var class = $("img").attr("class");
 console.log(class);
      });

            });
```

Back with another question. I have 3 images each with a different class (image1, image2, image3). If i run the code above the log will only show the class of the first image no matter what image I click on

Comment: Be aware that the identifier name `class` should be *avoided*, because it is part of the [Future Reserved Words](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.5.3) list, and in some implementations it will cause a `SyntaxError`, Safari is a good example of it...

Comment: i wasn't using it anyway i changed it when i pasted the code here, but thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Within your `click event handler`, replace `$("img")` with `$(this)`

like:

```
$('img').click(function(){ 
   var class = $(this).attr("class"); 
   console.log(class); 
});
```

`this` will reference to the specific object which is involved. You may also use the
`event.target` like `$(event.target).attr("class");`, if you declare `event` as parameter of your click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` inside the click event to get the current object.

```
$('img').click(function(){ 
    var class = $(this).attr("class"); 
    console.log(class); 
});
```